# Как получить данные с массива, который внутри объекта?

Tags: массивы, json, javascript

Как получить данные с массива "request_params", который внутри объекта и вывести с помощью console.log?

```
var data = {
    error: {
        error_code: 100,
        error_msg: 'One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: latitude is undefined',
        request_params: [{
            key: 'sig',
            value: '0b60a5c91837c3aa836f07561c75883c'
        }, {
            key: 'oauth',
            value: '1'
        }, {
            key: 'method',
            value: 'users.getNearby'
        }, {
            key: 'radius',
            value: '1'
        }, {
            key: 'v',
            value: '5.23'
        }, {
            key: 'access_token',
            value: '95a8d00de13afe81e92c7311f1df77c43a68ae06da61fdd5c60eb86b8db540b6ded4109f4967dcedce28e'
        }, {
            key: '_dev',
            value: 'f2cd6dcd4c00577a7d'
        }, {
            key: 'lang',
            value: 'en'
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log(data.error.request_params)` ? или, для надежности вывода:

```
console.log(data.error.request_params.slice(0)); //вывести копию
```